# Does the JVM have the ability to detect opportunities for parallelization?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, jvm

The Java Hotspot can optimize the sequential code very well. But I was guessing that with the advent of multi-core computers, can the information at runtime be useful to detect opportunities to parallelize the code at runtime, for example detect the software pipelining is possible in a loop and similar things.

Was any interesting work ever been done on this topic ? Or is it a research failure or some halting problem which is very hard to solve?

Comment: Normally, an ExecutorService or fork/join is a better choice.  Given the time it takes to distribute tasks between threads is high, its highly unlikely that an automatic compiler will be better than hand written code. Often for simple loops, using multiple threads is slower.

Comment: Lots of other compilers do this sort of thing these days, I see no reason why a JVM/JIT shouldn't.

Comment: From my practical experience, the JVM is actually pretty good at this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the current guarantees of the [Java memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model) make it quite hard to do much, if any, automatic parallelization at the compiler or VM level. The Java language has no semantics to guarantee that any data structure is even effectively immutable, or that any particular statement is pure and free of side-effects, so the compiler would have to figure these out automatically in order to parallelize. Some elementary opportunities would be possible to infer in the compiler, but the general case would be left to the runtime, since dynamic loading and binding could introduce new mutations that didn't exist at compile-time.

Consider the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = expensiveComputation(array[i]);
}
```

It would be  trivial to parallelize, if `expensiveComputation` is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), whose output depends only on its argument, and if we could guarantee that `array` wouldn't be changed during the loop (actually we're changing it, setting `array[i]=...`,  but in this particular case `expensiveComputation(array[i])` is always called first so it's okay here - assuming that `array` is local and not referenced from anywhere else).

Furthermore, if we change the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = expensiveComputation(array, i);
    // expensiveComputation has the whole array at its disposal!
    // It could read or write values anywhere in it!
}
```

then parallelization is not trivial any more even if `expensiveComputation` is pure and doesn't alter its argument, because the parallel threads *would* be changing the contents of `array` while others are reading it! The parallelizer would have to figure out *which parts* of the array `expensiveComputation` is referring to under various conditions, and synchronize accordingly.

Perhaps it wouldn't be outright *impossible* to detect all mutations and side-effects that may be going on and take those into account when parallelizing, but it would be *very* hard, for sure, probably infeasible in practice. This is why parallelization, and figuring out that everything still works correctly, is the programmer's headache in Java.

Functional languages (e.g. Clojure on JVM) are a hot answer to this topic. Pure, side-effect-free functions together with [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) ("effectively immutable") data structures potentially allow implicit or almost implicit parallelization. Let's double each element of an array:

```
(map #(* 2 %) [1 2 3 4 5])
(pmap #(* 2 %) [1 2 3 4 5])  ; The same thing, done in parallel.
```

This is transparent because of 2 things:

1. The function `#(* 2 %)` is pure: it takes a value in and gives a value out, and that's it. It doesn't change anything, and its output depends only on its argument.
2. The vector `[1 2 3 4 5]` is immutable: no matter who's looking at it, or when, it's the same.

It's possible to make pure functions in Java, but 2), immutability, is the Achilles' heel here. *There are no immutable arrays in Java.* To be pedant, *nothing* is immutable in Java because even `final` fields can be changed using reflection. Therefore no guarantees can be made that the output (or input!) of a computation wouldn't be changed by parallelization -> so automatic parallelization is generally infeasible.

The dumb "doubling elements" example extends to arbitrarily complex processing, thanks to immutability:

```
(defn expensivefunction [v x]
  (/ (reduce * v) x))


(let [v [1 2 3 4 5]]
  (map (partial expensivefunction v) v)) ; pmap would work equally well here!
```

Comment: This totally ignores the (relatively common) case of purely-arithmetic computations, which HotSpot should be able to parallelize as well as anyone else.  Can it?

Comment: @Louis: What exactly do you mean by "purely-arithmetic computations"? I don't know if HotSpot does it, but all modern processors are already doing [branch prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) and [speculative optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) so I'm not sure if HotSpot could add anything to that.

Comment: Instead of calling `expensiveComputation` methods, what about loops that just do math directly on arrays?

Comment: Dumb example: a loop doubling every element of an array.

Comment: You need 1) an array, which is mutable, 2) a * operator, which is pure, 3) a loop, which accesses the elements in that array *and writes them too* if you're modifying in-place. Let's assume, for simplicity, that the loop goes strictly from 0 up to `array.length-1`, no tricks, and let's create a new array to get rid of in-place modification, so we have 1) left. If the array is stack local and has not been leaked outside, *then* it's easy enough to prove that it's ok to parallelize. Even this "dumb" example needs to prove several things - because of mutability - so imagine the general case!